# Where should I place an edited containers class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, adobe

I would like to modify an Accordion class to suit my needs.

Instead of simply extending Accordion, I would like to copy and paste the whole class as a start, with the new class name "MyAccordion", into the src folder; to gain the maximum freedom(I assume).

However, several problems encountered. For the "include "../core/Version.as";" error, I had solved by replacing it with a explicit Version static const string. But for the problems lead by the inheritance, e.g. AccordionHeader, etc, I found that there would be too many files to be edited when going down the stream. I suspect I mis-understand the whole logic of editing the class.

Would anyone give me some help? May be some reference for me to read, or even just some keywords for me to search. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Well - for all the reasons your discovering, you actually don't have flexibility when leveraging "boilerplate" code like this. Use [Extend and Override](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/04/03/extends-override-and-super/) to properly modify existing classes:

```
package com.yourSite.src
{
    public class Foo
    {
         public function Foo
         { 
         }

         public function foo():void
         {
            trace("foo");
         }
     }
}


package com.yourSite.src
{
     public class Bar extends Foo
     {

          public function Bar
          {

          }

          override public function foo():void
          {
              trace("bar");
           }
      }
}
```

So, write a class that Extends Accordion, and override anything that you want to work differently. Any other functionality you may need can be added as required. OOP 101 :D

Check out the link above for a more cohesive discussion.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much Bosworth, I tried extends Accordion before but I found that I was not able to override the private functions, e.g. commitSelectedIndex() in Accordion.as. Is there a way to override the private function? This is why I had the idea to start from a copy and paste class. I am not sure if that's my problem or it's simply not sth extends can do.

Comment: Yep. A method must override publically accessible methods of it's superclass. Read up more [here](http://www.as3errors.com/1020-method-marked-override-must-override-another-method). As this article notes  '...any method marked private is invisible outside of its own class. You can’t override private methods because you don’t have access to them – so if you want the child class to redefine the functionality of the parent class’s private methods, you can just define new private methods. There’s no need to override.'

Comment: Sure thing - let me know if you have any other questions ;)